# What are the differences between "server", "workstation", and "desktop"?

Tags: meaning, nouns

From a book on Linux, I found the following text:

> A typical Linux system will run six virtual consoles and one graphical console
>
> - Server systems often have only virtual consoles
> - Desktops and workstations typically have both

Could anyone explain these three words, please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Précis

- Server: Designed to concurrently provide (shared) services to many people.
- Desktop: Designed for use by one person on their desk.
- Workstation: Usually a more powerful desktop.

## Server

### Hardware

A server is a computer that is used to provide shared services to many people. In a business context, the server is usually kept in a room dedicated to this purpose (the server room). Servers are often dedicated to one purpose: a file-server provides shared file-storage services to a group of people. An email server provides email collection, transmission and storage services to a group of people. This does not mean that the information is shared (though it can be) but that the computer and the services it provides are concurrently used by tens, hundreds or thousands of people. Servers are typically housed in tower or rack-mount cases. Servers do not typically have a dedicated screen, keyboard or mouse attached - they are managed by other means or by using a KVM-switch to share one keyboard etc between large numbers of servers.

---

Apart from the above, computer hardware designed for server use in an enterprise is often distinguishable from desktop computers (including workstations) in **some** or all of the following ways:

- rack-mount case.
- designed for "lights-out" usage.

  - out-of-band management.
  - boot-up messages diverted to remote monitoring devices.
- hardware RAID controllers.
- SCSI variants more often than SATA.
- front-accessible hot-plug disks.
- greater backplane bandwidth.
- higher noise levels.
- redundant hot-swap power supplies.
- support for SAN hardware.
- basic or absent graphics capability.
- often sold without a bundled keyboard or mouse.

There are home and SME "server" hardware devices which follow an almost opposite trend. They are designed to be very small quiet and unobtrusive and to sit on a desk or shelf. An example is the Excito Bubba, the size of a paperback book, sold without keyboard or mouse (it doesn't need one). These are also hardware designed specifically for a "server" rôle. There can be some overlap in form-factor with the "net-top" category of personal desktop computers.

### Other usage

Obviously, in general this term means "one who serves" and can be applied to waiters in restaurants for example. This term is also used for software, for example the Apache project's HTTPD software is invariably described as web-server software. Some people associate the term most strongly with software.

### Dictionary

[Oxford](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_gb0757670#m_en_gb0757670) says "a computer or computer program which manages access to a centralized resource or service in a network."

[image: rack-mount server][image: pedestal server]

## Desktop

### Hardware

A desktop computer sits on the desk of one person and is primarily dedicated to the use of a single person. Whilst it might be shared consecutively (e.g. in "hot desking"), usually only one person is using it at any given time. It doesn't matter if the main part of the computer is placed under the desk. Desktops are often in tower cases (sometimes horizontally under a monitor) or all-in-one cases combined with the display. A desktop computer usually has a dedicated display, keyboard, mouse and other peripherals directly attached to it.

### Other usage

Other usage isn't especially relevant but the term can obviously mean the upper surface of a desk. It can therefore be applied as an adjective for objects designed to be placed on that surface.

### Dictionary

[Oxford](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_gb0219630#m_en_gb0219630) says "the working surface of a desk.
(also desktop computer)a computer suitable for use at an ordinary desk.
the working area of a computer screen regarded as a representation of a notional desktop and containing icons representing items such as files."

[image: all-on-one desktop] [compact http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportDocument/c00323629/c00406696.jpg](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportDocument/c00323629/c00406696.jpg)

## Workstation

### Hardware

A workstation is a name usually reserved for a very high-performance desktop computer of the sort that might be used by scientists, engineers or on the trading floors of banks.

### Other usage

The word "workstation" has a more general use. In some cases it means a position equipped for a worker. Sometimes furniture makers describe use this word in the description of their [products](http://www.ikea.com/gb/en/catalog/categories/departments/workspaces/18967/). Some people use the term workstation to mean any personal computer. Sometimes the word is used to define a computer used, by one person at a time, for a specialised task.

### Dictionary

[Oxford](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_gb0960430#m_en_gb0960430) says "a desktop computer terminal, typically networked and more powerful than a personal computer."

[image: Workstation]

*images linked from hp.com and are probably (c)HP*

---

## Related Terms

### All-in-One

Here are some examples of current **all-in-one** desktop PCs:

- HP Omni 200t -- [The integrated, space-saving design of our Omni 200t series puts everything in the display](http://www.shopping.hp.com/webapp/series/category/desktops/200t_series/3/computer_store)
- HP All-in-one 200-5210 --  [HP Pavilion all-in-one 200-5210uk desktop](http://direct.tesco.com/q/R.210-3866.aspx)
- Dell Inspiron One 22 -- "[the sleek, space-saving, all-in-one Inspiron One 2205 desktop](http://uk.dell.com/uk/en/home/Desktops/inspiron-one-2205/pd.aspx?refid=inspiron-one-2205&cs=ukdhs1&s=dhs)"
- Apple iMac -- "[The ultimate all-in-one](http://www.apple.com/imac/)"
- Sony VAIO L-Series -- [all-in-one desktops](http://www.sony.co.uk/product/vd-l-series/tab/editorialarticle1)
- Lenovo C200 -- [Desktops & all-in-ones](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/desktops)
- Gateway ZX series -- [An all-in-one for everyone](http://www.gateway.com/programs/zxseries/index.php)

Comment: Source? It seems outdated, especially the parts about all-in-one cases and workstations...

Comment: I am the source. Perhaps I am an outdated sort of guy? :-) Feel free to suggest improvements or to edit my answer.

Comment: Sorry, this is not an accurate description on any of these terms, except, maybe Desktop.

Comment: I can't see any major problems with this answer. @Guffa, @cinqoTimo: can you be specific about what problems you find?

Comment: I agree with CesarGon. I dont find any problems with the answer.

Comment: @CesarGon: Have you seen an all-in-one case the last decade? They died out with the CRT screens...

Comment: @Guffa: The definitions are fine, and the answer is overall correct. I think you are splitting hairs with your argument about all-in-ones. It's not essential to the answer.

Comment: @Guffa: I have added some examples of **current** all-in-one desktop computers to the end of my answer (above)

Comment: Not a problem with the answer, per se, but to be technically correct, a server is a piece of software that runs on a computer.  A server is not the computer itself.  However, because of the abundance of central computers that host server programs only, it has become common to refer to those computers as 'servers'.

Comment: My problem with this is that the term workstation is not restricted to only high-end computers as you seem to suggest.  The term "desktop" is a subclass of a workstation.  Basically, beneath the class "computer," you have either: (a) a workstation or (b) a server.  I disagree with oosterwal.  There exists hardware that is specially designed to be used as a server.  Sure, without running Apache or Windows Server it isn't technically a server but it's pedantic to say that the hardware isn't a server.  In a general black-box sense of the word, it is, in fact, a server.

Comment: Actually, the more I think about it, you're not completely wrong with your definition of workstation.  In most instances, "workstation" is just the antonym of "server."  However in the CGI industry, manufacturers market their high-end PCs that are intended for design work as "workstations."  (http://www.boxxtech.com/, for example)

Comment: But I think the problem that most people have with this is that the terms aren't as black and white as this seems to make it.  Several of these are commonly used interchangeably and if you were to survey "experts" on them, they wouldn't hold up.  A lot of these terms just depend on what the marketing department at Dell and HP feels like they should be _this_ week.

Comment: I've expanded my answer to try to make it address the specific points raised. @advs89 these terms reflect my experience of their usage over 30 years, whilst language changes, I don't think it fair to talk about "this week"'s marketing spin. For example, I requisitioned my first workstation in 1993 I think.

Comment: I don't doubt you and I'm not trying to be argumentative but my point was that despite the fact that you have heard it used in a professional environment for over 30 years, I've heard it used in a more generic sense for the past 15 years. The point I was trying to make is that there is the definition you provided and then there is a much more generic one that is in common use today (in academia _and_ elsewhere).  I just think it's misleading to someone who might be reading this, perhaps an ESL student, who might see this and start using the term religiously with that one meaning.

Comment: Also: I agree with you on the "marketing spin."  I don't think it should be taken into consideration either.  I brought it up because  your earlier revisions cited the HP and Dell websites as sources.  (at first I thought you were basing it solely on that but from your comments I can see that you also have experience in the field).  I did mention that I have heard the term used in that way in CGI and other professional industries.  But in the software realm, in which I do a _LOT_ of reading, "workstation" is always referring to the computer of the end user.  (i.e. opposite of server)

Answer (score 4):

As reported by the NOAD:

- Server: a computer or computer program that manages access to a centralized resource or service in a network.
- Desktop: a microcomputer that is suitable for use at an ordinary desk.
- Workstation: a general-purpose computer with a higher performance level than a personal computer.

Comment: This is actually a better answer - although I disagree with workstation. A workstation is a computer that is designed to operate specific applications, often with a centralized datasource provided on a server, as opposed to a PC which is general use. There is no performance criteria. Actually, for cost reasons, business workstations tend to have less power than the average Desktop because of its limited scope.

Comment: "Incredibly powerful and scalable, the T5500 delivers dual-socket workstation performance in a compact, quiet package"  "Complex multi-threaded/multitasking application environments, including engineering, digital content creation and scientific computing." - [Dell](http://www.dell.com/uk/business/p/precision-desktops?cat=precision-desktops&view=standard)

Comment: @cinqoTimo: That is the generic definition of _workstation_. About the performance, Wikipedia reports that "historically, workstations had offered higher performance than personal computers".

Comment: "a desktop computer terminal, typically networked and more powerful than a personal computer." -[OED](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_gb0960430#m_en_gb0960430)

Comment: The definition of workstation is a little dated.  It has grown, in most industries, to be much more generic than that.  In common use (especially colloquially) it is simply antonymous (yes, that is a word) with "server".  Although, as I mentioned in my comment a few answers up, in the CGI industry and a few other professional industries, the old definition (suggesting higher performance) stands.